# CSS mozilla transition not working 

Tags: css

I have a simple transition to shift a footer img up 5px when hovered smoothly, however Firefox doesn't apply the smooth transition. Only webkit.

I have declared all vendor prefixes correctly as below.

```
    #footer img {
        margin-left:8px;
        -webkit-transition:all .1s ease;
        -moz-transition:all .1s ease;
        -ms-transition:all .1s ease;
        transition:all .1s ease;
        cursor:pointer;

#footer img:hover {
    position:relative;
    top:-5px;
```

You can check for yourself in Safari/Chrome VS Firefox. Go the the footer and just hover over each item.

[www.rjam.es](http://www.rjam.es)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firefox seems to require an initial value set first. Even if it's `0`.

```
#footer img {
     margin-left:8px;
     -webkit-transition:all .1s ease;
     -moz-transition:all .1s ease;
     -ms-transition:all .1s ease;
     transition:all .1s ease;
     cursor:pointer;
     position:relative;
     top:0;
}

#footer img:hover {
     top:-5px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I guess Firefox needed to see that it had top: defined for both states?

Answer (score 0):

While Pierre's answer has worked for me previously, I just recently stumbled upon a situation where it didn't. Implementing a simple, looping image slider, I use the following.

HTML:

```
<ul id="slides">
    <li class="active">
        <img src="/.../0.jpg">
        <p>Caption</p>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <img src="/.../1.jpg">
        <p>Caption</p>
    </li>
    <!-- and so on -->
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#slides {
    position: relative;
}
#slides li {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
}
#slides li.active {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

and jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    animateSlide();
});

function animateSlide(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var current = $('#slides li.active');
        var next = current.next();

        // If there is no next, use the first li
        if(!next.length){
            next = $('#slides li:first');
        }

        // Ensure both are displayed as block, to allow the opacity transition to show
        current.add(next).css('display', 'block');
        current.removeClass('active');

        setTimeout(function(){
            next.addClass('active');
            setTimeout(function(){
                current.css('display', 'none'); // Avoid elements overlapping each other
                animateSlide(); // Loop
            }, 1000); // The duration of the transition
        }, 1); // Workaround for letting the "next" var to render as block properly before applying the class which triggers the transition
    }, 6000); // Change image every 6 seconds
}
```

This works great in Safari/Chrome (though I admit somewhat quirky with all the `setTimeout`s), but while the slider was technically working in Firefox, there were no transition visible there.

Following [Jim Jeffers' answer to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3332179/638254), I was able to get it working smooth in both Safari/Chrome and Firefox, and it also substantially cleaned up my javascript.

Updated CSS:

```
#slides li {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
}
#slides li.active {
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Updated jQuery:

```
function animateSlide(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var current = $('#slides li.active');
        var next = current.next();

        // If there is no next, use the first li
        if(!next.length){
            next = $('#slides li:first');
        }

        current.removeClass('active');
        next.addClass('active');
        animateSlide(); // Loop
    }, 6000); // Change image every 6 seconds
}
```